# cordova detect if app was downloaded from Google Play

Tags: android, cordova

I'm making a Cordova 4.0 Android app that will be sold in Google Play, and I would like to prevent illegal use of it (for example preventing someone to extract the APK from the system and re-distributing it).

One theoretical way of doing this would be by checking that when the app is launched by the user, he did actually download it from Google Play (versus being it sideloaded). I'm not even sure if this is possible or if there's an alternate way of doing something like this.

One way that works in other cases is to use require some sort of login when accessing the app, but in this case I can't do that. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: any code want to share?

Answer (score 0):

Google offers a way to implement validation / licensing:
http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html

Take a look if this is what you need!

Comment: @michael_breker thanks for the link, but that seems to be a solution for native Android apps, I'm developing in HTML/JAVASCRIPT/CSS and then use Cordova to build the APK and Eclipse just to export the signed final APK...

Comment: I had a similar situation a while back when I needed a license check for a Phonegap app. I didn't find a reliable way to achieve this other than the official approach. Would be interested to know if there is one myself, actually! I didn't implement it natively back then, though. The app was never finished...

Comment: I found this ( http://teusink.blogspot.com/2013/02/phonegap-android-license-key-app.html?m=1). Did you ever get to try it? It seems that it's what we'd be looking for, but before trying it I'll have to learn how all the licensing stuff works. Besides, it looks like it might be tied to the developer account that publishes the app, but in my case I would be using the client's account  (which I don't have access to) so that might complicate things a bit. Also, I'm on Cordova 4.0, that seems to be made for 3+, not sure if it will still be compatible

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion would be for those apps which are get connected to a server to fetch some data.

App verification token

> - Generate an encoded 64-bit long token and store on both device & server as well. This will be a unique token per app
> - Whenever app tries to connect to server, it sends the device token details. Server needs to verify it before fulfilling its request.
> - On specific events, server can generate a new token for a device.

Same way, device token can be mapped to a user or an app on the server side.

Token could carry some app related information, *for instance*.

> - first 4 or 6 digits represent app size
> - second block of digits could represent user specific or device or some other details
> - Or another block could hold app contents modification date

In case of any change, server could verify the app size, last app contents modification dates, etc.

Generally it is recommended to uglify, obfuscate and minimize app resources before submission.

Comment: So I like the idea of using tokens, but I fail to see how to differentiate between apps downloaded from Google Play and sideloaded apps using this method... could you expand on that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package manager class to determine the source of an app (only google or amazon currently detected)

You can similarly use google analytics which gives same information.

This is pretty neat since Android stores the source of every package, allowing apps to know where they came from, to prevent piracy and sideloading.

Great if you always publish to google or amazon. Useless if you sideload your app.

Comment: is that a cordova plugin?

Comment: It is standard part of Android SDK